# How can I tell of a HTML attribute exists or not, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to convert to HTML5, but to preserve the site experience for those that don't have all the HTML5 features, I would use a workaround. For example, how can I check if the HTML5 attribute contentEditable exists, so that if it doesn't, I can just create a textarea instead.

Thaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet checks if the 'contentEditable' property exists.

```
if('contentEditable' in element){
   // contentEditable is available
}
else{
   // create textarea
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aZauL5K7

I have that code, but in IE6, it doesn't display any messages

Comment: Yes, positive. `var edit_region = document.getElementById('edit_region');` where `<div id="edit_region"></div>`

Comment: You said, it doesn't display any messages. Not even an error message? Where did you test for it's existence?

Answer (score 1):

This can help: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to [HTML5 Peeks, Pokes and Pointers](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/peeks-pokes-and-pointers.html):

```
"isContentEditable" in document.createElement("a")
```

You can replace the `document.createElement("a")` with any element, really, so if you already have an element you're working with, use that.