# Detect support for HTML5 <input form=""> attribute

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check whether a browser supports the HTML5 `form` attribute on `input` elements?

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178296/how-to-check-browser-support-for-html5-form-attributes), I've tried the following:

```
var supportForm = function()
{
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  if ("form" in input)
  {
    input.setAttribute("form", "12345");

    if (input.form == "12345")
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

... but that gives a false negative for FireFox (14, at least). Replacing `input.form` with `input.getAttribute("form")` gives a false positive for IE 9.

Comment: ordinarliy, I'd suggest Modernizr for this sort of thing, but it seems they haven't included a test for this one. Ho hum.

Comment: @SDC - I would agree - on both counts!

Comment: If you do manage to get a working test, consider contributing it to Modernizr.  :)

Comment: For the record, Modernizr now support this test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For input elements there was a reference to the parent form before the HTML5 form reference feature and this causes this problem you mention.

I hope there is a more elegant way to check if it is supported but for now you could use the following (but it involves dealings with the DOM):

```
function testInputFormSupport() {
    var input = document.createElement('input'),
         form = document.createElement('form'),
         formId = 'test-input-form-reference-support';
    // Id of the remote form
    form.id = formId;
    // Add form and input to DOM
    document.childNodes[0].appendChild(form);
    document.childNodes[0].appendChild(input);
    // Add reference of form to input
    input.setAttribute('form', formId);
    // Check if reference exists
    var res = !(input.form == null);
    // Remove elements
    document.childNodes[0].removeChild(form);
    document.childNodes[0].removeChild(input);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Looks promising - it chimes with what @Gaby is saying in his answer. I'll give it a go, and let you know if it works.

Comment: Initial tests are good. Needs a full bout of testing (and IE doesn't like document.childNodes[0].appendChild, since childNodes[0] is the html tag; but we can work around that!), but definitely looking good so far.

Comment: I had `body` in the place of `childNodes[0]`, it may help.

Comment: Not perfectly; IE complains `Unable to get value of the property 'removeChild': object is null or undefined` when executed in the head, but succeeds if run later. In my case (Rails, which likes to include all JS in a big minified wodge), I can get around this using jQuery (not sure why); I suspect the general solution would be to ensure you invoke the test function after document ready. However, otherwise this is golden!

Comment: You're right it should be called after DOM is initialized, using `window.onload` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is that easy.

According to the specs at http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fae-form

1. The form owner must exist in order to be set to an element.
2. The element must be in the document in order to alter its form owner

Comment: Aha. But this suggests a way forward. Could I add a form to the document, add a `hidden` `input` after it, and try to change the `form` attribute of that element? Then clean down afterwards?